# How to get uuid in the form of "9e316d9e-a018fdc02a8352dea61ffd1d"?

Tags: go, uuid

I know how to get uuid in the form of `uuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,` but I am required to get uuid in the form of  "9e316d9e-a018fdc02a8352dea61ffd1d".

I am using `https://github.com/satori/go.uuid`.

I tried but I cannot come up with the item to search on Google. (If you know the search item, then it is obvious).

Comment: both kinds have the same number of digits. Is you question about using substr like functions? Just split it by hyphens and reassemble it back

Comment: No. Does the number and position of "-" play a role in uuid?

Comment: It looks like number and position of hyphens matter in your case. So make your own function which gets 8-4-4-4-12 uuid, splits it into parts by ":-" and join array back.

Comment: The UUID itself is just a 128 bit number. The hex digits and the hyphens are just one possible way of formatting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one line:

```
// var u uuid.UUID
fmt.Sprintf("%x-%x", u[:4], u[4:])
```

Playground [example](https://play.golang.org/p/bsyYlNFqVr1).

---

**Edit:**

Since `fmt.Sprintf` is not the most efficient method for encoding, you could model off of [UUID.String()](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid/blob/master/uuid.go#L115) with this:

```
buf := make([]byte, 33)
hex.Encode(buf, u[:4])
buf[8] = '-'
hex.Encode(buf[9:], u[4:])
return string(buf)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aNWABdY9vVI)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible since a UUID is a 16-byte number per definition. But of course, you can generate 8-character long unique strings with substring-ing and unix timestamp.

Also be careful with generating longer UUIDs and substring-ing them, since some parts of the ID may contain fixed bytes (e.g. this is the case with MAC, DCE and MD5 UUIDs) and this form of UUIDs `9e316d9e-a018fdc02a8352dea61ffd1d` has no Guarantee to being really unique.